# Как сделать выход из скрипта при проверке условия?

Tags: mysql, sql

В шапке скрипта должна быть проверка на значение из базы.
Сделал процедуру с проверкой переменной. Внутри процедуры должно быть что-то такое:

```
      if (@var1 <> @var2) then
            exit
      end if;
```

Должно полностью завершить работу скрипта. И, если возможно, вернуть нужный статус  в консоль bash

Comment: Что такое "скрипт" в Вашем текущем понимании? Если хранимая процедура, то есть [LEAVE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/leave.html).

Comment: https://federico-razzoli.com/mysql-stored-procedures-all-ways-to-produce-an-output

Comment: Скрипт - подразумевается будут несколько запросов, но в начале перед этими запросами нужно добавить шапку с проверкой условий, если условие не выполняется, то запросы ниже не должны выполняться

Comment: Я спросил "что это". А не "что оно будет делать". Ну коли так, давайте по шагам. Кто его будет выполнять (не запускать на выполнение!) - bash или MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42927' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @text;
```